# Why are IF and ELSE colored in PHP, but ELSEIF is not?

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I just wrote an [answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856395/regular-expression-check-if-string-contain/19856855#19856855). I was describing a `if-elseif-else` algorithm in PHP and noticed, that the `if` and `else` expressions are in blue color, whereas the `elseif` term stays black. Is this the wanted behaviour or is this a bug?

[image: elseif not colored]
[image: elseif not colored (zoom)]

Comment: Interesting, I blame google (prettify)

Comment: +1 nice freehand circles

Comment: Zoom and enhance!

Comment: since you're using the curly braces syntax just use `else if`, which is in that case equivalent to `elseif`, and will also be correctly highlighted...

Comment: @m0sa: Cue all the coding style zealots who now have a new reason to recommend `else if` and bash `elseif`: "because the Stack Overflow syntax highlighter doesn't recognize `elseif`..."